# Changing NaN cells in pandas dataframe with different type of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

How can I fill all the NaN values in pandas dataframe with the empty value of column type. For example, I have 2 columns - "Name" - str, "Age" - int. I want to fill all the NaN cells in "Name" with "" and all the NaN in "Age" with 0. Do pandas has a method to implement it. I can do that separately for "Name" and "Age" but I want to let pandas determine the type of column by himself and in dependence of this type change NaN to either "" either 0. Thank you in advance.

Comment: One quick reserach on google is enough to answer your question: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html.
Please, try google your issue before posting here.

Comment: What if you have a date? Or something else than a string/number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `value` of [**`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) accept dictionnaries. So, assuming your dataframe is `df`, you can fill `NaN` values with multiple values in multiple columns by using :

```
df.fillna({"Name": "", "Age": 0}, inplace=True)
```

Furthermore, if you need to fill `NaN` values based on the type of the columns, use this :

```
df= pd.concat([df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).fillna(0),
               df.select_dtypes(include='object').fillna("")], axis=1)
```

*NB: The code above will work properly only if your dataframe holds string and/or numeric columns*.